# Is it good practice to have multiple dynamoDB connections in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a scenario where there are multiple dynamoDb tables say table_a, table_b, table_c. I need to connect to these tables from spring boot app depending on the incoming request.If the spring boot app receives request to read from A then read from table_A. Each table has different access keys and secret keys.I am using AWS SDK AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder to connect to the table.
My question is can I have multiple AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder connections in spring boot. I think each client builder maintains its own pool of connections. Is there any better way to solve this.

Comment: Yes you can. Just a word of advice, one application should have one and only one DynamoDB table, having multiple tables smells of moving a relational database to DynamoDB without redesigning the data layer. Don't trust me, trust the guy who does this for a living :D - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k

Comment: Thanks @Augusto for your reply. I totally understand what you are saying. I am not creating a relational DB. its just multiple DynamoDBs which store different information. I am sure it does not make sense without clearly explaining the use case. My concern was that if i have too many connections, say 10 connections to DynamoDb, would it impact the performance at some point or is it normal to do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

There's no "connection" semantics in DynamoDB, it's just a bunch of isolated HTTP requests. All you get from maintaining a connection is things like pooling if underlying TCP connections etc, there are no semantics at the database level associated with a connection.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I came across this in aws docs "Client Lifecycle
Service clients in the SDK are thread-safe and, for best performance, you should treat them as long-lived objects. Each client has its own connection pool resource. Explicitly shut down clients when they are no longer needed to avoid resource leaks.
To explicitly shut down a client, call the shutdown method. After calling shutdown, all client resources are released and the client is unusable." I was wondering if I have too many clients, it would impact the performance?

Comment: I suppose the answer to that isn't really dynamodb specific. If you have thousands or tens of thousands active TCP connections, then you'll eventually run out of resources, but that applies to any system where you have keep-alive connections under the hood :)